# How to convert Long to BigDecimal while also using a Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, long-integer, bigdecimal

I'm struggling to understand how can I make the following code work.

The field `count_human_dna` of my `stat class` is of type `BigDecimal`, with setting the type as Long this works, but I need to change it to `BigDecimal`, can somehow tell me how could I make this work for `BigDecimal` field?

```
stat.setCount_human_dna(dnaSamples.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getType().equals("Human"))
    .collect(Collectors.counting()));
```

This code is counting all the `dnaSamples` which type belong to Human.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple and efficient way to do is to use terminal operation [`count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count()) which returns the number of elements in the stream as `long` and then convert into `BigDecimal`:

```
stat.setCount_human_dna(getDNACount(dnaSamples));
```

```
public static BigDecimal getDNACount(Collection<Sample> dnaSamples) {
    long humanSamples = dnaSamples.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getType().equals("Human"))
        .count();

    return BigDecimal.valueOf(humanSamples);
}
```

---

And you can produce the result of type `BigDecimal` directly from the stream using [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) a terminal operation:

```
stat.setCount_human_dna(getDNACount(dnaSamples));
```

```
public static BigDecimal getDNACount(Collection<Sample> dnaSamples) {
    return dnaSamples.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getType().equals("Human"))
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,
                (total, next) -> total.add(BigDecimal.ONE),
                BigDecimal::add);
}
```

*Sidenote:* I'm not an expert in such questions as DNA analysis, but the result of this reduction will always be a whole number. You might consider utilizing `BigInteger` instead of `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Thank you, I am still improving and learning how to properly use all this Functional Paradigm stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `BigDecimal#valueOf` method for the conversion from `long` to `BigDecimal`.

```
stat.setCount_human_dna(BigDecimal.valueOf(dnaSamples.stream().filter(x -> x.getType().equals("Human")).collect(Collectors.counting())));
```

See the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for more detail.

Comment: That assumes that the `counting` collector doesn't overflow the `long` counter that it uses.   Granted that overflow is implausible ... but if that is the case, why does the `count_human_dna` property need to be a `BigDecimal`?

Comment: In the case its possible that it overflows, im not sure if this is possible with streams to have the count as a bigdecimal from start

Comment: If my calculations are correct, and you're counting molecules of human DNA, then you need 30-35 tons of pure DNA to reach a number that's too big for a `long`.  If your samples are bigger than one molecule, then scale that up accordingly.

Comment: You don't need to utilize a collector, simply apply `count()` as a terminal operation.

Comment: @StephenC overflowing a `long` while counting is as implausible as getting digits after the decimal point, so using `BigDecimal` here is debatable for sure. If we assume the computer to be as fast as counting one element per nanosecond, it still requires over 290 years to overflow the `long` range. And if the source is as compact as requiring only one bit per element, it’s still over 1,000,000 TB. And this is counting only elements passing the filter…